# Inferring the implementation of a function in c++

Tags: c++

I was going through the documentation of `rand()` function in c++ and it says

> The function accesses and modifies internal state objects, which may cause data races with concurrent calls to rand or srand. Some libraries provide an alternative function that explicitly avoids this kind of data race: rand_r (non-portable). **C++ library implementations are allowed to guarantee no data races for calling this function.**

As a more general question how can I be sure that I am calling a c++ implementation of a function (`rand` in this case)?

- Calling `rand()` inside a file having `.cc` or `.cpp` extension.
- or, any particular header that can ensure this

I am asking this question because my understanding is that when I use `cstdlib` header, it in turn calls the c implementation of that (`stdlib.h`). If that's not case then does c++ provide its own implementation for all c functions?

Comment: Workaround: Don't use `rand` and instead use the facilities from [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)

Comment: The correct solution is to not use `rand`.

Comment: as per the man page for `rand` it says to use `rand_r` if you want a more threadsafe version.

Comment: C libraries are also allowed to guarantee no data races. To figure out whether the implementation you're using is thread-safe, RTFM.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking the wrong question.

You've read that C++ library implementations are allowed to give you a version that has no data races. They are *allowed*, but they are not *required* to do so. If you had some all-knowing oracle capable of telling you whether you are using a C++ implementation, and if it told you that you are, would that solve your problem? No, not really, because you still wouldn't know whether that implementation would guarantee the absence of data races. Maybe it would, but you'd have no certainty.

So you have to ask the right question: how do I know whether the function I'm using guarantees that? And the answer is: check the *specific* documentation of the library you are using! I suppose you are reading the [cplusplus.com page on rand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/). That is a generic site, unrelated to a specific library, so it won't help you answering this question. Instead, what compiler and standard library are you using? Check their documentation. If the authors state that their `rand` function is guaranteed to be race-free, then go ahead and use it. Otherwise, be conservative and assume there are some races, and don't use it.

And by the way, a lot of people would tell you that that site should be avoided, because it isn't very reliable. In general, [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) is preferred. And it says that

> It is implementation-defined whether rand() is thread-safe.

Where "implementation defined" means exactly what I said. And if you continue reading, it will also list some other problems (the numbers it generates aren't that random after all), and

> It is recommended to use C++11's [random number generation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) facilities to replace rand().